# Highlight region with a darkened background

Tags: gimp

I am struggling to do this in Gimp 2.8.22-1.

https://s.natalian.org/2018-01-05/gimp.mp4

I used to be able to do this like so: http://dabase.com/blog/Highlighting_a_region_in_a_screenshot/

What am I missing? Any other tips to highlight a region of a graphic?

Comment: can you [edit] and expand your question to explain what do you mean? I really don't want to go through a video to understand your problem. The core of it should be written in the question, links are just for support.

Comment: Adding images - that is, full desktop screenshots - of what you want to achieve, and of what you got, would also have helped to solve this in much less time than watching the videos. Also, describing the steps you take in written form may help to find answer yourself in general, though likely not in this specific case.

Comment: Sorry, I have limited time on this planet. I've put a series of images together to make a video to explain the issue. I annotated them with my voice.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is:

1. make a selection around what I need
2. **Invert** the selection (`Select>Invert`) (to select the rest of the picture)
3. Use `Colors>Brightness/Contrast` to reduce the **contrast** over the rest of the image (and possibly slightly reduce the brightness as well).
4. In the more extreme cases apply a slight Gaussian blur (2-3) pixels

In other words what I want to highlight remains untouched, it is mostly the rest of the image which is dimmed.

[image]

(Image above: `Contrast -30` and that's it).

Comment: Add "0. Change the Image mode to RGB", and this will work :)